# pass 2 json object rest full

Tags: json, rest

```
@POST  
@Path("create")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) 
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String create(String user, CostAPIHandle apihandle,CostDataSize datasize){
    String serid = "serid" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    return save(user, serid, apihandle, datasize);
}
```

Can you show me anotation to use in this case (post a string and 2 object)

- CostAPIHandle have 2 properties (float: price, int: package_size )
- CostDataSize have 3 properties (float: price, int: datasize , int: dataunit)

And the string value how does it look when you post through http ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one approach is to create a new java class with the variables that you want to use like below:

```
public class SomeClassName {
    private String user;
    private CostAPIHandle apihandle;
    private CostDataSize datasize;

    // getters & setters
}
```

and then changing your method to accept it as an input

```
@POST  
@Path("create")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) 
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String create(SomeClassName input){
    String serid = "serid" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    return save(input.getUser(), serid, input.getApihandle(), input.getDatasize());
}
```

Comment: This way i thought before, you have any different answers, is it the limit of Restful, it just pass single object ? Thanks for your answers.